# Error: NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AuthorModule)[ScrollbarHelper -> ScrollbarHelper -> ScrollbarHelper -> ScrollbarHelper]:

Tags: angular, typescript, abp, ngx-datatable

I'm following abp framework tutorial and Author route give the folowing error "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AuthorModule)[ScrollbarHelper -> ScrollbarHelper -> ScrollbarHelper -> ScrollbarHelper]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for ScrollbarHelper!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AuthorModule)[ScrollbarHelper -> ScrollbarHelper -> ScrollbarHelper -> ScrollbarHelper]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for ScrollbarHelper!"
[image]

project in github:
https://github.com/heitorgiacomini/Xpto.Livraria-AngularFrontEnd

https://github.com/heitorgiacomini/Xpto.Livraria-BackEnd

Comment: Do you have the annotation `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` above the `ScrollBarHelper` class definition?

Comment: There is no @Injectable. ScrollBarHelper is a third party library.

Comment: Can you provide the URL for this library's NPM page?

Comment: @AllanJuan @swimlane/ngx-datatable

Answer (score 2):

Did you try providing the service to relevant module where the service is used.
Note the **providers** array

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ScrollBarHelper]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

UPDATE: **NgxDatatableModule**

Try adding **NgxDatatableModule** import

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, NgxDatatableModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ScrollBarHelper]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: added the providers: [ ScrollbarHelper, DimensionsHelper, ColumnChangesService],
and the error changed to 
Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AuthorModule)[DatatableComponent -> DatatableComponent -> DatatableComponent -> DatatableComponent]:

Comment: Have you added NgxDatatableModule to imports array

Comment: Unable to import component DatatableComponent.
  The symbol is not exported from C:/PROJETOS/Angular/Xpto.Livraria-AngularFrontEnd/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/swimlane-ngx-datatable.d.ts (module '@swimlane/ngx-datatable').

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Solved by importing NgxDatatableModule into AppModule.

Comment: didn't work. I think the only solution is redo the abp tutorial